# When/whether to use "ineō" instead of "eō"

Tags: verbs, word-comparison, word-choice, irregular-words, compound-verb

I am learning Latin for the first time this year, and I have a question about the usage of the verb 'eō', *I go*. The textbook that I am using, *Henle Latin 1st Year,* lists 'eō' as follows:

> eō, īre, īvī (iī), itum, *irreg., intr*.         *go*

However, it then proceeds to list the following "compound of eō," 'ineō':

> ineō, inīre, iniī, initus, *irreg., tr.*         *go into*
>                                                            *enter upon*

Now, my question is, how can I determine whether to use 'in xxx eō' or just 'xxx ineō' or even 'in xxx ineō' to say "I go into xxx?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All three are fine!
While there might be a slight difference in nuance, I would say that you can freely use any of them that feels best in that situation.
There just turns out to be many ways to express the same things, and there are a great many other verbs for similar purposes like *ingredi* and *intrare*.

There are examples in Lewis and Short:

- You can use [*inire*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=ineo&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) with plain accusative or *in* plus accusative.
  The first examples in the linked L&S dictionary entry are the most concrete ones for entering e.g. a building.
- The entry for [*ire*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=eo1&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) also has plenty of examples for *in* and accusative with *ire*.