# Why were prefixes repeated as postverbal prepositions?

Tags: affixes

> French: [s'abstenir de](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/abstain)    Spanish: [abstenerse de](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=abstain)    English: [abstain [from] (v.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=abstain&searchmode=none)
>   late 14c., "to withhold oneself,"
>   from Old French abstenir (14c.), earlier astenir (13c.) "hold (oneself) back, refrain, **abstain (from)**, practice abstinence,"
>    from Latin abstinere "withhold, keep back, keep off,"
>   from ***ab(s)-* "from, away from"** (see [ab-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ab-&allowed_in_frame=0)) + tenere "to hold" (see [tenet](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=tenet&allowed_in_frame=0)).
>
> French: [adhérer à](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/adhere)    Spanish: [adherir a](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=adhere)    English: [adhere to (v.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=abstain&searchmode=none)
>   directly from Latin *adhaerentem* (nominative *adhaerens*), present participle of *adhaerere* "stick to,"
>   from *ad-* "to" (see ad-) + *haerere* "to stick" (see [hesitation](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=hesitation&allowed_in_frame=0)).
>
> French: [appartenir à](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/appertain)   English: [appertain [to] (v.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=appertain&searchmode=none)
>      late 14c., from Anglo-French apartenir, Old French apartenir (12c.) "**be related to**; be incumbent upon,"
>   from Late Latin appertinere "to pertain to,"
>    from ***ad-* "to, completely"** (see [ad-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ad-&allowed_in_frame=0)) + pertinere "to belong to" (see [pertain](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pertain&allowed_in_frame=0)).

1. Literate Anglophones and Francophones were fluent in Latin, and comprehended the Latin prefixes, when these verbs were borrowed from Latin. 
   So why did English and French repeat the Latin prefix as a postverbal preposition?
2. To wit, couldn't intransitive verbs above be ditransitive?

For the following cognates, the English cognate appears more redundant than the French and Spanish ones. English  added the prefix ***en-***  , but 'ENdow' must still be followed by 'WITH'. French didn't add any prefixes and conveys ***en-*** with 'de'.

> French : [doter qqn de qch](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/endow) (= endow somebody WITH something) 
>   Spanish: [dotar de algo a](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=endow)
>   English: [endow (v.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=endow&searchmode=none) [...] from ***en-* "in"** (see [en-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=en-&allowed_in_frame=0) (1)) + Old French *douer* "endow,"
>   from Latin *dotare* "bestow" (see [dowry](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=dowry&allowed_in_frame=0)).

Answer (score 4):

> Literate Anglophones and Francophones were fluent in Latin, and comprehended the Latin prefixes, when these verbs were borrowed from Latin. So why did English and French repeat the Latin prefix as a postverbal preposition?

The same was done regularly in Latin as well!
One can say [*in X ineo*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/13615/79) or [*ex X exeo*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=exeo&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059).
This kind of repetition is quite typical, and communication is often improved by redundancy.

It may also well be that a prefixed verb becomes detached from its original compound meaning and becomes a more independent verb.
This is particularly natural for borrowed verbs; the English "adhere to" works best with an English preposition "to".
Although some will understand that *ad-* means "to", most will not.

> To wit, couldn't intransitive verbs above be ditransitive?

Perhaps they could, but they aren't.
Languages don't always evolve in the most logical way.

Comment: In fact, one finds that the Latin verbs behind the first 2 example in the original question are used in just this way in the extant literature (abstinere ab, adhaerere ad).